# How to use a dictionary instead of a list for calculating option greeks?

Tags: python, pandas

This is our sample dataframe, df:

```
Date           Expiry      Strike Price  LTP    Open Int    Underlying Value    Days
2019-06-04   2019-06-27       12500     19.9    1945425         12021.65         23
2019-06-10   2019-06-27       12500      6.5    2708100         11922.70         17
```

I have calculated the option greeks using the below code:

```
def greek(underlyingprice,strikeprice,interestrate,expirationdate,callprice):
    
    x = mibian.BS([underlyingprice,strikeprice,interestrate,expirationdate], callPrice 
                  callprice)
    
    IV = x.impliedVolatility
    
    c = mibian.BS([underlyingprice,strikeprice,interestrate,expirationdate], volatility = IV)
    
    delta = c.callDelta
    
    theta = c.callTheta
    
    rho = c.callRho
    
    vega = c.vega
    
    gamma = c.gamma
    
    return [delta,theta,rho,vega,gamma,IV]

      
underlyingprice = df['Underlying Value'].values

strikeprice = df['Strike Price'].values

expirationdate = df['Days'].values

interestrate = 7.3

callprice = df['LTP'].values

    
final = []
for i, j, k, l in zip(underlyingprice, strikeprice, expirationdate, callprice):

    final.append(greek(i,j,interestrate,k, l))
    
    
final = pd.DataFrame(np.array(final))
final.columns = ['Delta','Theta','Rho','Vega','Gamma','Implied Volatility']
final[['Underlying Value','Strike Price','LTP']] = df[['Underlying Value','Strike 
        Price','LTP']]
final.reset_index(inplace=True)
final.head()
```

This code is working absolutely fine.

Output:

```
Delta   Theta   Rho Vega    Gamma   Implied Volatility  Underlying Value    Strike Price    LTP
0.118572    -1.772300   0.885692    5.985913    0.000574    11.459351   12021.65    12500   19.9
0.050060    -1.076517   0.274938    2.656285    0.000327    12.268066   11922.70    12500   6.5
```

Problem Statement:

1. I have taken final as a list and then converted into a Dataframe, however if I take a dictionary, how would I execute then?
2. If I don't want to use for loop ,how can I use functions such as apply or assign for every value?

Comment: Could you elaborate? What part of your code exactly would you want to be a dict, instead of a list? And why?
Your *greeks* returned from `greek` do not appear to have a particular key assigned to them. Why would a dictionary be needed?

Comment: I appended the values of greek function into a list named final,so for the sake of learning I thought how this would be executed If I take a dictionary instead, or I can put it this way, is it possible to use a dictionary here? Second part of the question is how can use function such as apply etc instead of for loop?

Comment: In python, you have a thing called *list comprehension*. You could use that instead of a for loop.
`final = [greek(i, j, interestrate, k, l) for i, j, k, l in zip(underlyingprice, strikeprice, expirationdate, callprice)]`
This way, you would get a list.
I would not recommend using a dict in this particular example, however you could always make something nasty, like:
`final = {idx: greek(i, j, interestrate, k, l) for idx, (i, j, k, l) in enumerate(zip(underlyingprice, strikeprice, expirationdate, callprice))}`
And there you have a dict. But its pretty useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code with `apply` by changing your function signature:

```
def greek(row, interestrate):
    underlyingprice = row['Underlying Value']
    strikeprice = row['Strike Price']
    expirationdate = row['Days']
    callprice = row['LTP']

    x = mibian.BS([underlyingprice,strikeprice,interestrate,expirationdate], callPrice=callprice)   
    IV = x.impliedVolatility  
    c = mibian.BS([underlyingprice,strikeprice,interestrate,expirationdate], volatility=IV)
    new_cols = pd.Series(
        {
            'Delta': c.callDelta,
            'Theta': c.callTheta,
            'Rho': c.callRho,
            'Vega': c.vega,
            'Gamma': c.gamma
        }
    )
    return pd.concat([new_cols, row[['Underlying Value','Strike Price','LTP']]])

interestrate = 7.3
final = df.apply(lambda x: greek(x, interestrate), axis=1)
print(final)
```

Output:

```
      Delta     Theta       Rho      Vega     Gamma  Underlying Value  Strike Price   LTP
0  0.118572 -1.772300  0.885692  5.985913  0.000574          12021.65         12500  19.9
1  0.050060 -1.076517  0.274938  2.656285  0.000327          11922.70         12500   6.5
```